# About sufficient conditions for very structured positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose one is given a set of positive real numbers $\{ a_i >0 \}_{i=1}^S$ and set of vectors $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^S$. Now consider the matrix, $M = \sum_{i=1}^S a_i x_i x_i^\top$.

- What are some of the easy to state conditions so that $M$ is positive definite?
- Suppose that the matrix $M_x = \sum_{i=1}^S  x_i x_i^\top$ is given to be positive definite.

  Then what can be a condition on the numbers $\{ a_i >0 \}_{i=1}^S$ so that $M$ is positive definite?

Comment: As written, $M$ is trivially positive definite, since $y^TMy = \sum_{i}a_i (x^Ty, x^Ty)$, which is a sum of products of non-negative numbers.

Comment: Not seeing your argument. $y^\top M y = \sum a_i ||x_i^\top y||^2$. We need this sum to be strictly above $0$ for all $y \neq 0$. How is that true without something more?

Comment: if you want a different argument: $M_x':= \min(a_i)\cdot M_x \succ \mathbf 0$ then $M=M_x' + \sum_{i=1}^S \beta_i\cdot \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T$ where each $\beta_i\geq 0$ and make use of the fact that the sum of a positive definite matrix and a positive semidefinite matrix is necessarily positive definite

Comment: Yes. So if $M_x$ is PD then there is a way to argue that $M$ is PD. But otherwise its not clear - which is my first point.

Comment: If you want strictly positive definite, then it suffices that there is no $y$ that's simultaneously orthogonal to all $x_i$. So if you form a matrix $X$ whose rows are $x_i$, then it's equivalent to that matrix having a trivial kernel. This is independent of any other assumptions on $a_i$.